# How do I check if the exact string I am searching for is listed in a file?

Tags: node.js

I am trying to write a function that would search for a given string(exact string) in a file and prompt if it is listed in that file in node.js. I have tried the below script but it lists the string even if my search string is listed as substring in the file. 
I have message.txt that would include following words:

```
bat
bait 
can 
cat
```

My script to search for the string in a file is

```
var fs = require('fs');
fs.readFile('message.txt', function (err, data) {
    var searchstr = "bat";
      if (err) throw err;
        if(data.indexOf(searchstr) < 0){
               console.log("String not found");
      }
        else{
            console.log("String found!");
        }
});
```

So, here I am searching for `bat` using `searchstr` which apparently would output as "String found". Now, the problem is, if i give `at` as search string, it would output as "String found" because "at" is a substring of `bat` and `cat` as per the file. 
But, I'd like the function to output "String not found" when I search for `at`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regular expression here:

```
/\bat\b/
```

Will match `at` surrounded by any word boundaries. You then need to change your code a bit:

```
var fs = require('fs');
fs.readFile('message.txt', function (err, data) {
    var searchstr = "bat";
    var pattern = new RegExp("\b" + searchstr + "\b");
    if (err) throw err;

    if (pattern.test(data) === false) {
        console.log("String not found");
    } else {
        console.log("String found!");
    }
});
```

Depending on your exact requirements you might have to change the regular expression. For example, you might want to test for `at` surrounded by whitespace instead: `/\sat\s/`.